# Out of memory loading image on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, out-of-memory

My app needs to load the same image a certain number of times. Thus, I need to manage the memory usage because after a few iterations it runs out of memory. I am trying to use Garbage Collector, but it isn't working. I am doing this in my Content Page.

My code looks like:

```
private async Task ExecuteTests(string imageResource) 
{

    // Do stuff

    for (int q = 0; q < NUMBER_OF_TESTS; q++) {

        // Do some work

        await LoadImageAsync (imageResource);

        // Do stuff

        if (q < NUMBER_OF_TESTS - 1) {
            stkImage.Children.Remove(mImageTested);
            mImageTested = null;
            GC.Collect ();
        }
    }
}

private async Task LoadImageAsync(string imageURI) 
{
    mImageTested = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
    Task<ImageSource> result = Task<ImageSource>.Factory.StartNew(() => ImageSource.FromFile(imageURI));
    mImageTested.Source = await result;
    stkImage.Children.Add(mImageTested);
}
```

Comment: I think you made a misstake in your example. It adds a couple of new Images to stkImage.Children and then removes the last one. The others are still present in stkImage.Children so the GC.Collect() cannot remove them. I'm also wondering why you need to make multiple Images for the same image? Can't you just use the reference to one Image multiple times? That will save you memory.

Comment: @JaccoDieleman, it is for graduate purpose. I am creating kind of a benchmark. In this part of the work I need to load an image around 50 times and measure the average time to load it. I could do this manually, e.g. run each execution and measure its time and then calculate the average, but I would like to do this inside a loop, if it's possible of course. If I use one image reference, my measure will not be precise.  

What I am trying with this code is:
- Add one image
- If it is not the last execution, remove it and call GC.Collect()

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you manage the memory:

https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading